# Navigate View Controller from Custom Collection View Cell Without using Segue

Tags: swift, uicollectionviewcell, viewcontroller

I have made a custom collection cell and design the cell interface using separated .xib file. Now I want to navigate the view to another view controller when the user click the cell.

But it gives me this error

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

And here is my code:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let productDetailsVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("productDetailsVC") as ProductDetailsViewController

    // The next line is where the error occurs.
    productDetailsVC.label.text = self.products[indexPath.row].productName

    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(productDetailsVC, animated: true)

    //self.presentViewController(productDetailsVC, animated: true, completion: nil)


}
```

I have checked the value inside self.products[indexPath.row].productName and it exists. I checked it using break point. Do you guys have any idea what's the problem.

btw could u guys also explain what's the different between pushViewController and PresentViewController method.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much mosedw I got the solution for your question.I tried the solution for another stackoverflow questioner but when I saw the solution for the question I went through your question.Then I tried giving answer your question too.Now I got the both the solution.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) 
{

   let productDetailsVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("productDetailsVC") as ProductDetailsViewController

   // The next line is working fine now
   productDetailsVC.passDataToLabel = self.products[indexPath.row].productName

   self.navigationController?.pushViewController(productDetailsVC, animated: true)

}
```

In ProductDetailsViewController

```
var passDataToLabel:String!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    label.text = passDataToLabel
 }
```